# Do I have to protect against cross domain request forgery?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cross-domain, nonce

From my research, the proper way to protect against this is to set a NONCE with every GET request that returns a form and then check for the NONCE on the POST request. However, someone could still write a script to GET my form along with the NONCE and then POST it back with the NONCE.


Since this is such a widely known vulnerability, shouldn't browsers already take care of that by not allowing cross-domain ajax calls? If not, does ASP.NET MVC 4 already have a built-in mechanism to protect against this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a built in mechanism. [HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175(v=vs.118).aspx), which can be used to help protect your application against cross-site request forgery. To use this feature, call the AntiForgeryToken method from a form and add the [ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateantiforgerytokenattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute to the action method that you want to protect.

CSHTML file:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Controller:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(User updatedUser)
```

You'll note that the token involves two safety measures -- a form field and a cookie:

> To generate the anti-XSRF tokens, call the @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
> method from an MVC view or @AntiForgery.GetHtml() from a Razor page.
> The runtime will then perform the following steps:
>
> 1. If the current HTTP request already contains an anti-XSRF session
>    token (the anti-XSRF cookie __RequestVerificationToken), the security
>    token is extracted from it. If the HTTP request does not contain an
>    anti-XSRF session token or if extraction of the security token fails,
>    a new random anti-XSRF token will be generated.
> 2. An anti-XSRF field
>    token is generated using the security token from step (1) above and
>    the identity of the current logged-in user.
> 3. If a new anti-XSRF
>    token was generated in step (1), a new session token will be created
>    to contain it and will be added to the outbound HTTP cookies
>    collection. The field token from step (2) will be wrapped in an  element, and this HTML markup will be the return
>    value of Html.AntiForgeryToken() or AntiForgery.GetHtml().

Reading:

[XSRF/CSRF Prevention](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages)

[Wikipedia CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. However, on a side note, how would a NONCE protect me if the attacker can still have the browser make a GET request, get the NONCE and then POST the form with the NONCE in it?

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes how would you reckon they do that? Sounds like the attacker is sitting at the user's computer.

Comment: They can serve a page to the browser with JavaScript that does just that.

Comment: No they can't: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy Unless you have allowed them to using CORS

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes if you read the link in StefanH's answer, you'll see that the `AntiForgeryToken` is comprised of not only a form field, but also a cookie. The attacker won't be able to fake or read a cookie that belongs to your domain.

Answer (score 2):

Those nonces are used for protecting against cross site request forgeries.  A cross domain ajax call is not necessary to make that happen - and browsers do have protections against those.  CSRF is a vulnerability because when a browser makes a call to your site, it sends the session information for your site, regardless of the page that told the browser to make the call.  The browser can be told to make a get request to your site.com by including an img tag on evilsite.com that points to a page on your site.com.  If when that get request is processed by yoursite.com you validate the nonce, there is no way that a drive by of evilsite.com would know the nonce.  Similar things can be done for post requests as well.

This page seems to have some information about how to mitigate this in ASP.NEt MVC:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: GET requests should not be of a concern, since you should never be doing sensitive tasks with GET requests. POST requests are what I'm concerned about. How would a NONCE protect me if the attacker can still have the browser make a GET request, get the NONCE and then POST the form with the NONCE in it?

Comment: Because when the get is performed (again, as an image tag or something similar) the contents of the page are not actually accessible by the calling page, so there is no way for the evil page to get at the nonce.

Comment: Not if I make the GET request through an `<img>` tag, but I can make the GET request using AJAX and JSONP.

Comment: While they shouldn't, they often times do.  For instance, is your logout page accessed by a get or a post?  Would you want your users logged out of your site by simply visiting a forum or other site where an attacker might be able to control the html?

Comment: And that is where the browser protections come in.  Unless you have enabled cross domain requests on your web server, you should be protected by that.

Comment: My log out page is accessible through a GET request, but that's not something I'd call "critical". Also, how would the server know where the request is coming from? Do browsers send the domain they are currently in with every request and I didn't know about it all this time?

Answer (score 1):

You should also take a look at the concept of stateless CSRF protection. There are 2 standard approaches to achieving this: the Encrypted Token Pattern and the Double Submit Cookie pattern. [The Encrypted Token Pattern](http://insidethecpu.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/encrypted-token-pattern/) leverages a Rijndael-encrypted Token which contains a built-in nonce value that can’t be read by scripts, and is a very strong cryptographic structure.

Comment: Your pattern has become part of an [OWASP recommendation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) to prevent CSRF attacks.